# Images not showing next to each other in Laravel

Tags: css, laravel

I'm trying to add few images next to each other in my website, when I adding the bellow code they are showing bellow of each other not next to each other, how I can fix that?

```
<div v-if="!isMobile" class="head-carousel">
<head>
 <style>
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

    .columnx {
    float: left;
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 5px;
}

  /* Clearfix (clear floats) */
   .rowx::after {
   content: "";
   clear: both;
   display: table;
}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="rowx">
    <div class="columnx">
    <img src="https://vindax.com/resource/image/2020_02_14/1581644803381.png" 
    alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
     </div>
     <div class="columnx">
     <img src="https://vindax.com/resource/image/2020_02_14/1581644803381.png" 
      alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
       </div>
       <div class="columnx">
        <img src="https://vindax.com/resource/image/2020_02_14/1581644803381.png" 
       alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
       </div>
       </div>

         </body>
          </div>
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with Laravel. You can put them in a row with CSS.

Comment: @Bulent ok what need to put in css file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code, just put out your img link below the img, not creating a new div

```
<div v-if="!isMobile" class="head-carousel">
    <head>
        <style>
            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .columnx {
                float: left;
                width: 33.33%;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            /* Clearfix (clear floats) */
            .rowx::after {
                content: "";
                clear: both;
                display: table;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="rowx">
            <div class="columnx">
                <img src="https://vindax.com/resource/image/2020_02_14/1581644803381.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
                <img src="https://vindax.com/resource/image/2020_02_14/1581644803381.png" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
                <img src="https://vindax.com/resource/image/2020_02_14/1581644803381.png" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
            </div>       
        </div>
    </body>
</div>
```

Comment: Or you can use `<span><img src="https://vindax.com/resource/image/2020_02_14/1581644803381.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%"></span>` On each img